# Is it possible to add styling to the HTML body tag in a XPage?

Tags: xpages

I would like to add styling to the body tag, currently I end up with this code:

```
<body class="xspView tundra">
<div style="margin: 0px">
```

but I would like to achieve this:

```
<body class="xspView tundra" style="margin: 0px">
```

Is this possible without removing existing functionality (i.e. without removing dojo and default xpages functionality)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can,

if you have for example one xpage called 'home'. You can add your style definitions to the   tag in the xpage. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" styleClass="ddd" style="margin: 20px;">
// your content goes here
</xp:view>
```

If you have a multiple xpage design and you dont want to add these lines of code to every xpage you could use Themes to automaticaly add the styles to the body tag:

```
<control override="false">
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>xspView tundra</value>
    </property>
    <property mode="concat">
            <name>style</name>
            <value>margin: 20px</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Comment: It works!! I decided to take the theme approach :) Thanks again Jeroen.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use a theme to add a style to the XPages body tag.  You can do it right on the Page itself under the style property.  The source looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    styleClass="myBodyStyle">

    </xp:view>
```

Which renders to the browser as:

```
 <body class="myBodyStyle">
```

Comment: Well, doing that will overwrite theme-based classed and it may not be desirable all the time.

Comment: Serdar, that depends on how it's defined in the theme. The "webstandards" theme for instance adds the theme's classes to what is already there:

  <!-- View Root (Page Body) -->
 <control>
  <name>ViewRoot</name>
  <property mode="concat">
   <name>styleClass</name>
   <value>xspView tundra</value>
  </property>
 </control>

Comment: I meant the standart themes (oneui or webstandard). Try that :)

Comment: Thimo has warned me. In webstandard and oneui (v1) themes, it works in 'concat' mode. But after oneuiv2 (including v2.1), if you specify a class for your body, it will replace theme-based classes which results in losing visual design... the best shot would be using an additional theme for that.

Comment: Many thanks David, I wish I could select two answers as accepted answer - I am new to Stackoverflow! Many thanks for welcoming me on here and providing instant feedback.

Comment: Thanks Serdar for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

Add a css file that has a BODY entry. Put your margin there. Add the css to a theme if u want to use it globally

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it in a css file? Include this:

```
 body {
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

Just like any HTML styling...
Or, maybe I don't exactly understand what do you mean...

Comment: Thanks - I thought about this as the easiest option.